# Trying to sell an ETF only traded in Berlin and AMEX

Tags: etf

I use Flatex for trading stocks and I bought 16 shares of [SPDR S&P Internet ETF](https://www.boerse-berlin.com/index.php/Funds?isin=US78468R1279) on the Berlin stock exchange. It gained in value (~22%) and I'd like to sell it. For 2 months *nobody* wants to buy it (in Berlin). The only other place this ETF is traded at is AMEX. Flatex told me I can't sell it there because the stock is stored with Clearstream Lux.

I realize the buy was a mistake and I should have done my research about the ETF. But how do I get rid of it?

Edit: Just to add that Flatex is absolutely useless in helping me with this. When I tried to sell on AMEX the UI only told me that I don't have enough shares to sell. Took them 2 months to get back to my inquiry about the error message.

Edit 2: I put in an offer at market and after a *looong* time waiting I somebody bought took it up. I didn't get the best price but a decent profit none the less.

Comment: Are you sure it's AMEX and not NYSE Arca? SPDR S&P Internet ETF (XWEB) is listed on NYSE Arca.

Comment: At least that's what the Flatex UI tells me :-/

Comment: Is there a bid/ask? how much would you loose when selling market?

Comment: I'm selling market, even then there are no takers. I see that the price fluctuates, but nobody is taking up my offer.

Comment: @TomTom According to the Deutsche Börse webpage linked in the question, the bid size is 1,024 at 97.68 EUR, and the ask size is 992 at 100.82 EUR. 0 volume in the last two months. I don't know how reliable the data is.

Comment: Well, so with a size that large you can just sell market. Done. 97.67 out.Or you put in a limit order 1 cent higher and see whether anyone takes it.